# Alternative way to handle form submission on Netlify powered website?

Tags: forms, form-submit, netlify

I am building my first website with netlify as host and one feature is a form submission. Netlify can handle submissions although the free feature is limited to 100 submissions / month. My question: Does anyone know of ANY alternative ways to submit forms to avoid having to pay if my website would exceed this limit?? I know that for example php is blocked. I would like to send the forms directly to a given email.

Thanks for all future wisdom!